# For what are disk signatures being used for by GNU/Linux (distributions) / grub?

Tags: boot, grub, dd, mbr

I am talking about disk signatures in context of the [MBR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record). The area from 441 to 445 bytes.

For what does the GNU/Linux kernel, GNU/Linux distributions usually use disk signatures for?

I only found wikipedia and [this](https://lkml.org/lkml/2003/12/19/139) as reference, that (MBR) disk signatures are in context of Linux used for something at all.